# Date measure to filter Values exhibiting inconsistent behaviour

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

**I am facing the following problem:**

*Some additional info: I have to get the latest FX of a certain type to use this as my restatement rate. I do this with a calculated true/false column:*

```
bool_Latest_FX_Act = 
var latestDate = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(FX_Table[Month-Year])
    ,FILTER(ALL(FX_Table)
        , FX_Table [Type] = "Actuals"
    )
)
return
IF((FX_Table [Month-Year] = latestDate) && (FX_Table [Type] = "Actuals"), TRUE(), FALSE())
```

This returns true if the rates are the most recent rates. False if not. (it works) This doesn't really apply to the problem but explains how I get the true/false for the CP measure.

I have this model:
[image: PBI Model]

I have created two measures that each return 1 date:

[CP] & [CP_PY]

(Current Period) & (Current Period Last Year)

```
CP = 
VAR ThisActMonth =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCT (FX_Table[Month-Year] ),
        FX_Table[bool_Latest_FX_Act] = TRUE ()
    )
RETURN
    ThisActMonth
```

This measure returns February 2019 in date format:

[image]

I use this measure as a Boolean in a measure to filter my values:

```
CP Actuals = SUMX(
     FILTER (ValuesTable, ValuesTable [Type] = "Actuals" && ValuesTable [Month-Year]=[CP]),
            ValuesTable [RestCurrAct]
     )
```

When I use this measure, results are returned as expected, my data is filtered by type and by the latest FX period (changes dynamically with whatever is loaded in the model).

For Prior Year:

```
CP_PY = SUMX(
    Filter('Date', 'Date'[Date Hierarchy]=[CP]),
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[Date Hierarchy])
)
```

This measure returns February 2018:
[image]

When I try to use the CP_PY measure to filter my values nothing is returned:

```
LY Actuals (NoFX) = SUMX(
     FILTER (ValuesTable, ValuesTable [Type] ="Actuals" && ValuesTable [Month-Year]=[CP_PY]),
            ValuesTable [USDNoFX(xElim)]
     )
```

I have checked that the period measures are identical to the ValuesTable[month-year] values and I have made sure that there are in fact prior year values ;) . I have a feeling it is the way my CP_PY is written but I have no idea where I am going wrong. I am really confused by why this is working for CP and not for CP_PY. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
FILTER ( ValuesTable, ... )
```

The table you are filtering, `ValuesTable`, is not necessarily the whole table but is being evaluated *within your current filter context*. I'm guessing that you are attempting to evaluate that measure within a context that does not include February 2018, which means that adding the `[CP_PY]` condition will make the `FILTER` function return an empty set since it cannot simultaneously include and exclude that month.

There are a few ways to fix this. A simple one might be to wrap `ValuesTable` in an appropriate variation of `ALL`, `ALLSELECTED`, or `ALLEXCEPT`. That is, something like

```
FILTER ( ALL ( ValuesTable ), ... )
```

I'd recommend rewriting the measure though to look something more like this:

```
LY Actuals (NoFX) =
VAR PrevYear = [CP_PY]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( ValuesTable[USDNoFX(xElim)] ),
        ValuesTable[Type] = "Actuals",
        ValuesTable[Month-Year] = PrevYear
    )
```

Comment: Thank Alexis,
I will mark your answer; Wrapping the Values table in a variation of ALL etc. bizarrely does not work. However; declaring the "variable measure (CP_PY)" as a variable as you've illustrated in your example solved the problem. Any idea why this would happen? Thanks for your help, really appreciated.